# Criteria using belongsTo field return empty result

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two controllers: timesheetcontroller and consultant controller. In Timesheet I have field:

```
class Timesheet {

...
String orderNumber
String groupCode

static belongsTo = [consultant: Consultant] //here
...
```

And in Consultant:

```
class Consultant {
...
    String userName
...
```

How can I build a query, which will filter list of timesheet by the name of consultant ? I'm trying something like this below, but it doesn't work.

Getting a name of consultant:

```
<input type="text" id="consultant" name="consultant" value="${flash.consultant}"/>
```

And in TimesheetController:

```
def list = {
    flash.consultant = params.consultant //here
    flash.groupCode = params.groupCode
    flash.orderNumber = params.orderNumber

    if(!params.max) {
        params.max = 20
    }
    def query
    def criteria = Timesheet.createCriteria()
    def results

    query = {
        and{
            like("userName", '%' + params.consultant + '%') //here
            like("groupCode", '%' + params.groupCode + '%')
            like("orderNumber", '%' + params.orderNumber + '%')
        }
    }

    results = criteria.list(params, query) 

    render(view:'index', model:[ timesheetInstanceList: results ])

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:
You can use [findAll](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) method and reefer to consultant in HQL.

```
results = Timesheet.findAll("from Timesheet timesheet where timesheet.consultant.userName like :userName and timesheet.orderNumber like :orderNumber and timesheet.groupCode:groupCode",
                [userName: "%${params.consultant}%",orderNumber:"%${params.orderNumber}%",groupCode:"%${params.groupCode}%"],
                [max: params.max,offset:params.offset])
```

Comment: Using this code, there is no errors, but the result is incorrect. Returns all value from timesheetInstanceList, not only the records with typed consultant name.

Comment: change loggingSql = true in dataSource config and check/paste here sql generated.Also print values of params.consultant, params.groupCode and params.orderNumber

Comment: Hibernate: select TOP(?) this_.timesheet_id as timeshee1_6_0_, this_.consultant_id as consulta2_6_0_, this_.group_code as group5_6_0_, this_.order_no as order7_6_0_ as total9_6_0_ from eci_timesheets this_ where (this_.group_code like ? and this_.order_no like ?)
Hibernate: select this_.consultant_id as consulta1_1_0_,this_.user_id as user6_1_0_, this_.user_name as user7_1_0_ from eci_consultants this_

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
In previous answer i do not pay attention to belongsTo i though it is    hasMany.However this answer will work.